# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.util.Args - Which dependency should I add?

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven

I'm running a Java application and had the following error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.util.Args

I believe that the issue is that one library is trying to use this `org.apache.http.util.Args` class with reflection, but is not finding it.

What should I add in my Maven pom.xml file to resolve this dependency?

My classpath already contains the following reference that should be related with this class:

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.6/httpclient-4.3.6.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.3.6/httpclient-4.3.6-sources.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4-sources.jar"/>
```

My `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add the follwoing dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

And for the future: typically, your favorite search engine can tell you which jar file you need; searching for

"org.apache.http.util.Args which jar"

directly send me to

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpcore43beta1jar.htm