# How Path Class(WatchService) work with FileBody for API Call

Tags: java

My java program will monitoring a directory, if the directory have new coming file, it's will take the file and send it to my server via API call. The file must send in one piece,so I can't use any **Reader** to read the content of file
 This is some part of my sample program

```
for(WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents())
                {
                    WatchEvent.Kind<?> type = event.kind();
                    Path fileName = (Path)event.context();
                    System.out.println(fileName+  "is a new file");
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.27:8008/file");
                    String ConvertFile = String.valueOf(fileName); 
                    FileBody bin = new FileBody(new File(ConvertFile));
                    HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create() 
                               .addPart("display_name", bin)
                               .build();
                    post.addHeader("filename", ConvertFile);
                    post.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

This is the portion of my code that I suspected bring me the error message which show in the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/util/Args
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.AbstractContentBody.<init>(AbstractContentBody.java:48)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.<init>(FileBody.java:89)
    at FileDetect.main(FileDetect.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.util.Args
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

I suspect is the **FileBody** can't take my **Path** class which consist of my new file information. I had tested if there is a new file appear in my directory,  `System.out.println(fileName+  "is a new file");`able to conduct it's job properly,telling me new file reached, May I know the `(Path)event.context();`syntax will get the content of the file or file name only and what is the data type of filename in my source code ? The **FileBody** will collect the file and send it to my server via API call

Answer (score 0):

'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' error occur because of the class loader cannot find the class so you need to use httpcore.jar library. 
you can download jar file from :

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpcore43beta1jar.htm

check this :
[org/apache/http/util/Args (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError). Message payload is of type: String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771696/org-apache-http-util-args-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-message-payload-is-o)

Comment: the httpcore jar had been included

Comment: hi, it's works now, thanks for your suggestion, I add in the newest version jar file and it's work