# Android , Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am facing a problem with Eclipse,

When I imported my project from one system to another system eclipse , It stopped working,

Error Message I am getting " E/AndroidRuntime(10125):   Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: "

I have already closed the project the restarted the eclipse and then again open the project still getting same problem.  Also updated the SDK manager to 6.0 , but same problem .
I am using Eclipse 4.4.2

Any one have solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098639/fatal-exception-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lorg-apach

Comment: check your imports by right clicking on the project, and **JavaBuildPath** , check for libraries in **Android** label

Comment: check the libs files weather they are properly imported or not. Right click on project->build path->configure build path and check libraries section